# Android AsyncTask wait other function to finish

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I try to execute two function asynchronously in android. So i need that the first function waid the second function. I try to use the AsyncTask to do this.But the problem is that the first function can not wait until the first function finished.

```
    private class DemandeConge extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("we are here", "**************On pre Exceute......***************");
        p=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        p.setMessage("Please wait...It is downloading");
        p.setIndeterminate(false);
        p.setCancelable(false);
        p.show();
        Log.i("we are here", "**************On pre Exceute......***************");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("we are here", "**************oOn doInBackground...***************");
        getSoldeConge();
        Log.i("we are here", "**************On doInBackground...***************");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i("we are here", "**************onProgressUpdate...***************");
        Log.i("we are here", "**************onProgressUpdate...***************");
    }

    /**
     * `onPostExecute` is run after `doInBackground`, and it's
     * run on the main/ui thread, so you it's safe to update ui
     * components from it. (this is the correct way to update ui
     * components.)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {

        Log.i("we are here", "**************onPostExecute...***************");
        Log.i("we are here", "**************onPostExecute...***************");

        Log.i("we are here", "add conge()");
        p.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        p.dismiss();
        Log.i("we are here", "**************onCancelled...***************");

    }
}
```

I have two function the first is `getSoldeConge();` which fetch some data with retrofit and the second will be exexuted when the second finised `Log.i("we are here", "add conge()");` but in my case the second function will run bofore the first fuction finished.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit calls are already done in a background thread, so you don't need to call them from an `Asynctask`. We'll need to see the Retrofit code to help you any further.

By the way, you shouldn't be using `AsyncTask` in 2020. If you're going to stick with Java, use RXJava. Or `ExecutorService`.